# parametro genérico en metodo

Tags: c#, genericos

es posible en la declaración de un método definir que el parámetro recibido sea un tipo indeterminado y evaluar dentro que tipo de parámetro ha recibido y actuar en consecuencia?
Es decir me gustaría hacer algo así:
dependiendo de el objeto que reciba lo creará o lo actualizará.

```
private void ActualizaArticulos(List<T> Articulos)
{
    if(Articulos.GetType()==CProductosNuevos)
    {
        //crea productos
    }
    else
        //actualiza productos

}
```

¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es posible, seria un método genérico, solo tiene que construirlo correctamente, podría ser de esta manera:

```
        private void ActualizaArticulos<T>(List<T> articulos) where T : class
        {
            if(articulos.GetType()== typeof(List<Articulo>))
            {
                //crea productos
            }
            else
            {
                //actualiza productos
            }
           

        }
```

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba muchas gracias.